# Fixed number of template function arguments according to template argument

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm currently looking for a solution to give a templated classes’ constructor and function a fixed template according number of arguments `N`. My template is of the form `template<typename T, unsigned int N>`. The idea is that the following will work:

```cpp
MyClass<int, 4> object(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

While the following should fail (and so on):

```cpp
MyClass<int, 4> object(1, 2, 3);
MyClass<int, 4> object(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

I'm thinking about something like `MyClass(T arg1, ..., T argN){...}` but automatically generated. I only found solutions on how to give a template one or many arguments. But nothing on fixed count.

I Hope somebody can help me. Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a constraint to the overload, such as

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct MyClass {
  // pre-C++20
  template <typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Args) == N, int> = 0>
  MyClass(Args&&... args) { /* ... */ }

  // or alternatively, post-C++20,
  template <typename... Args>
    requires (sizeof...(Args) == N)
  MyClass(Args&&... args) { /* ... */ }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31a3feb6b1b9de12)

Note that in the case `N == 1` then in a couple of cases these templates will be preferred over the automatically generated copy constructor. If this is a potential issue then you will need to further constrain the templates to prevent this case. [Here is an example of how you might do so.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c881d2c3d2769947)

If you don't need to use SFINAE to discern between other constructors, you could instead use `static_assert` as well:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
MyClass(Args&&... args) {
  static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == N);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Care should be done with forwarding constructor as non const lvalue will choose that constructor over copy constructor (when N == 1).

Comment: @Jarod42 true; I'll clarify that in the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You might use intermediate type and using `std::index_sequence`:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t>
using always_t = T;

template <typename T, typename Seq> struct MyClassImpl;

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
struct MyClassImpl<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    MyClassImpl(always_t<T, Is>...);
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using MyClass = MyClassImpl<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a89753c84f8f542).

Or, similarly, with simpler `MyClassImpl`, and complexity is moved in the alias:

```
template <typename ...Ts>
struct MyClassImpl
{
    MyClassImpl(Ts... args);
};

template <typename T, std::size_t>
using always_t = T;

template <typename T, typename Seq>
struct MyClassAlias;

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
struct MyClassAlias<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = MyClassImpl<always_t<T, Is>...>;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using MyClass = typename MyClassAlias<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0493a6b3f44d95a3)

Comment: I've never seen this approach before, but this is clever. I like this.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you work's fine but isn't there a cleaner solution without the whole std lib workaround? The problem is that I'm trying to write a project that is easy to understand for beginners. So that solution would be a bit to advanced for starters...

Comment: @Ohjurot: You might go to something like `MyClassImpl2<int, int, int, int>` which is probably easier to understand than `MyClassImpl<int, std::index_sequence<0, 1, 2, 3>>`. and use another form of alias for `MyClass`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I will take a look into that. The other answer also looks promising. I will do some more test on what works best in my case.

Comment: @Ohjurot: Added a second version with simpler `MyClassImpl` (complexity is now in alias).